# Extract string from custom object on listView item click

Tags: android, listview

I have created my own class (Course) to hold multiple strings and pass the object to populate a list using ArrayAdapter and AsyncTaskLoader (the strings are being filled from a JSON api).

Let's say I have these 3 Strings inside my class:

```
private String mCourseTitle;
private String mTime;
private String mTrainer;

public String getCourseTitle() {
    return mCourseTitle;
}

public String getTime() {
    return mTime;
}

public String getTrainer() {
    return mTrainer;
}
```

I want to set up an item click listener inside my Fragment that when tapped, shows a toast message with only the Course Title String and I'm kinda stuck...

How do I extract the title to show it in a Toast from the clicked item?

```
 // Create a new adapter that takes an empty list of days as input
        mAdapter = new DayAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Day>());

        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        //on item click Listener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Show the title
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), Title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer

```
 //on item click Listener
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
             Course yourCourse = yourList.get(position);
              String yourCourseTitle = yourCourse.getCourseTitle();
            // Show the title
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), Title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Course currentCourse = listView.get(position); says it cannot resolve method get(int).

Comment: Is not listView.get(position) , use the list of your objects, I mean the ArrayList or List.  How are you creating the adapter?

Comment: My bad, it was supposed to be an ArrayList

Comment: I need to figure something out, it says that a non-static method get(int) cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: Declare your arraylist as global variable in your activity, don't use static. 
Or another way is create new method in your DayAdapter to retrieve the list of objects and do this call Course yourCourse = mAdapter.yourmethod(position);

Comment: I ended up going with Course selectedCourse= mAdapter.getItem(position);

Comment: nice :), don't forget to vote up if my answer help you